# Maximum distance between two towers for space wave propogations

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, signal-processing

Context: Space waves are a form of radio wave propagations, a space wave travels in a straight line from the transmitting tower. The problem here is related to line of sight communication.

[image]

In the above figure, the left side tower is the transmitter and right side tower is the receiver.

In this [website](https://www.shaalaa.com/question-bank-solutions/derive-expression-maximum-line-sight-distance-between-two-antennas-space-wave-propagation-propagation-electromagnetic-waves_3730), the following derivation for maximum  distance between antennas for transmission is derived.

Deriving max distance for transmitting antenna:

[image]

By Pythagoras,

$$(R+h_t)^2 = R^2 + d_r^2$$

where $R$ is radius of earth, $d_r$ is the max distance from tower to horizon.

We can approximate height of transmitter in the folloing way:

$$ 2h_t R >(h_t)^2$$

We can isolate for $d_r$ as :

$$ d_r = \sqrt{2Rh_t}$$

Now it is said that for two towers of height $h_{t}$ (transmittor) and $h_{r}$ (receiver), the maximum distance for transmission is given as:

$$ d_{max} = \sqrt{2Rh_t} + \sqrt{2Rh_{r} }$$

I do not understand as to why it is that the total distance allowed between the two towers is the sum of distances. As in , how can the radio wave emitted by transmittor tower for sure reach the receiver tower for a distance over it's line of sight? Do we assume that it's tall enough to be 'hit' by the signal?

---

Edit : I found this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon#Distance_to_the_horizon) helpful

Comment: Because that's the maximum distance to join the tip of the two towers with a straight line.

Comment: This answer assumes that the arclength - which would be the ground distance - is actually the same as $d_r$.  This will only be valid for small heights (compared to $R$) but I suppose that’s reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is the distance from each tower to where the radius of the Earth first begins to intersects their line of sight. So it is the distance from one tower to the radius point plus the radius of the second tower to the radius point.

Comment: If the receiver exists over the line of sight of the first tower, how is it possible that it can receive the waves?

Comment: It will receive the waves as long as they clear the radius, that is the maximum distance.

Comment: So, are we actually assuming that the second tower is tall enough such that the signal from transmittor just has to  pass through horizon

Comment: I think I see what troubles you, the formula describes 3 points on a line. It may be more accurate to change the = sign to the  < sign perhaps?

Comment: Ok, so if I got this right, we assume the towers are tall enough such that juts passing through horizon guarantees that the other tower gets the beam?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple. Just consider Earth to be a uniform sphere. Now, when we represent it in 2-D, we consider it to be a circle. Here, we have to find the maximum distance possible for the two towers to maintain contact. Now consider the tip of the two towers as two points. We know that the tangent connecting any two points barely touches the circle. So, it's quite obvious to consider the maximum distance at which the towers can maintain contact to be a tangent. You might have noticed that when we considered the triangle, we took $d_r$ to be perpendicular to the radius of Earth. For any circle, we consider the angle between the tangent and the radius to be $90°$. In this question we consider Earth to be a uniform sphere. So if $d_r$ is perpendicular to the radius of Earth, that means $d_r$ is a part of the tangent joining the tip of the both the towers.

Comment: Yes, I understood this, I am having a doubt only on how it's gaurenteed for the first tower to hit the second

Comment: @Buraian, See my edits.